# Как отслеживать нажатия на кнопки в модуле discord components discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

Всем привет, я решил попробовать сделать игру, на кнопках, но у меня появились трудности, а именно я не понимаю как именно происходит отслеживание их нажатия, буду признателен если подскажете.

Comment: конкретизируйте вопрос, приложите код, как Вы пытались решить проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос нужно конкретизировать, но вроде понятно, что вы хотите, из [документации](https://devkiki7000.gitbook.io/discord-components/guide/getting-started) видно, что модуль `discord_components` связан с discord.py, и из примеров понятно, что методу `wait_for` данный модуль добавляет `button_click`, то есть можно получить объект нажатия на кнопку.

У объекта `interaction` в [доках](https://devkiki7000.gitbook.io/discord-components/api-reference/interaction) показаны атрибуты и методы

```
@bot.command()
async def button(ctx):
    await ctx.send(
        "Hello, World!",
        components = [
            Button(
                   label="WOW button!",
                   custom_id="button1"
            )
        ]
    )
    interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check=lambda i: i.custom_id == "button1")
    await interaction.send(content="Button clicked!")
```